# Detect in Javascript which form has been submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, form-submit

I have a rating system for a bunch of entries on a website, they are programatically placed in and therefore I have given them a unique form identifier by using a count.

```
<form name="star">
    <input type="radio" class="star" name="rating" id ="rating" value="Terribad"/>
    <input type="radio" class="star" name="rating" id ="rating" value="Meh"/>
    <input type="radio" class="star" name="rating" id ="rating" value="OK"/>
    <input type="radio" class="star" name="rating" id ="rating" value="Pretty Good"/>
    <input type="radio" class="star" name="rating" id ="rating" value="Awesome!"/>
    <input type='hidden' name='item' id = 'item' value='<%out.print(item);%>'>
</form>
<span id = "msg<%out.print(item);%>" style = "float:right; margin-left:0px; padding-top:0px;"></span>
```

I also have another hidden field which is the users name here (retrieved in the javascript) but removed it because its large and from a complex session based array.

I've also added the count in a hidden field to help try and sort it out.

From there I'm running a javascript on the click of one of the radio buttons that will grab some more details from the session, and do an AJAX database update.

```
$(function() {
    $(".star").click(function() {
            var submission = document.getElementsByName("rating");
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var item = $("input#item").val();
            var rating;
            for (i = 0; i< submission.length; i++) {
                    if (submission[i].checked) {
                            rating = submission[i].value;
                    }
            }
            var submitted = 'name='+name + 'rating=' + rating;
            //alert (item);return false;
            $.ajax ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/process_rating.jsp",
                    data: submitted,
                    success: function () {
                            $('#msg'+item).html("Submitted");  

                    }
            });
            return false;
    });
});
```

This all works fine on the first entry (when I didn't have that count in) but as I am not surprised all the other entries are being treated as the first. The main issue is when I try and update the msg div with its success it only does the first one as it is grabbing the hidden value from the first form, not the form that was actually submitted.

This is all inside a jsp btw.

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "this" from the event handler function to look for the form which is the parent.

```
$(".star").click(function(){

    var formThatWasSubmitted = $(this).parents("form") 

});
```

Pretty sure that's how it works.

Comment: That code works but formThatWasSubmitted just returns [object] [Object]. But on thinking on it further maybe finding out the form isn't the correct thing to do. The hidden type is always being returned as 1 whereas is should be the item number I click on.

Comment: formThatWasSubmitted in that case will be a jquery object wrapped around a form.

Comment: Would formThatWasSubmitted have the correct value of "item" then? Because currently its getting the value of the first hidden item on the page. If so whats the attribute to pull this out, I'm pretty crap at javascript

Comment: Although not completely what I needed this is what I used to get it to work var id = $(this).parents("form").attr("id"); and I added an id to the form and it worked like a charm. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **each id should be unique on the page** and you shouldn't need any of the ids in your example.  This could very well be the root of many issues on your page.

Your code can be simplified quite a bit and you can use the "form" property on an input element to find the associated form.  Does this work better for you?

```
$(function() {
    $(".star").click(function() {
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/process_rating.jsp",
            data: {
                name: this.form.name,
                rating: $(this).val()
            },
            success: function () {
                // Not sure what you're trying to do here...  Update some input
                // that you didn't show in your code?
                $('#msg').html("Submitted");  
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I wasn't sure what you were trying to do upon successfully saving the form.  Let me know and we'll see if we can get it working.

Comment: If you're referring to the ID of the radio buttons this variable is actually returning correctly according to the radio button I click. The real problem is (probably should of explain this better) that the success function doesn't know what div to update because the id of the hidden field is always 1 and therefore only updates the 1st div (actually a span) to say Submitted, not the item that actually god submitted. I'll add code to my original question to help

Comment: BTW that success function only inserts the word Submitted into the msg div upon successful completion of the script